# Dpkg error exit status 2

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

Tried to install jenkins.deb and I got the shown below. Any ideas?

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i jenkins_1.609.1_all.deb 


(Reading database ... 118056 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking jenkins (from jenkins_1.609.1_all.deb) ...
dpkg-deb: file `jenkins_1.609.1_all.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing jenkins_1.609.1_all.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins_1.609.1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

The package install rule of the Makefile is creating the Debian package using `xz` compression.

Now, this kind of compression is supported by versions of `dpkg` `equal` or `higher` than `1.15.6.`

So, in order to solve your problem, you should `update dpkg` to a `newer version.`

Or install `gdebi`, and install with that application.

I download the package and install it `gdebi`. In `Xubuntu 15.04` package `daemon` is required